# Setting up parameters for linear referencing tools in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, parameters, python-toolbox, linear-referencing

I am attempting to write a python script to utilize the [Create routes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/linear-referencing/create-routes.htm), [Locate features along route](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/linear-referencing/locate-features-along-routes.htm), and [Make route event layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/linear-referencing/make-route-event-layer.htm) tools from the Linear Referencing tool box. The ultimate goal is to write this into a python toolbox as a custom tool.

I am having an issue with defining the "out_event_properties" parameter on both the locate features and make event tools. As per the [Esri documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/linear-referencing/locate-features-along-routes.htm) for these tools, the data type of this parameter is a "Route Measure Event Property" and I am not sure how to define this parameter.

It is a single parameter that defines up to four subparameters [image: screenshot from Esri documentation]. When you pull the linear referencing toolbox into python, there is only one space for this parameter, although I need to define several [image: screenshot from VSCode]. Also note that it is called out_event_properties in the locate features tool and in_event_properties in the event creation tool.

Here is a snip of some of my code:

```
route = arcpy.lr.CreateRoutes(input_line,route_ID_field,"route","LENGTH")

table = arcpy.lr.LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes(input_points,route,route_ID_field,radius,"out_table","RID")

SP_Out = arcpy.MakeRouteEventLayer_lr(route,route_ID_field,table,route_ID_field,"station_points")
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to run the tool from toolbox in ArcGIS Pro on some sample data then go to history and right click on the run tool and choose copy python command and paste that into your IDE, you will see exactly what it has placed there, my guess a list.